# How to fix "latin-1 codec can't encode characters in position" in requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-unicode

I am having trouble with encoding in python 3.
When I was testing on my PC I get no errors:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jun 24 2019, 04:54:02) 
[GCC 9.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> print(requests.get('https://www.kinopoisk.ru').text)

everything good.
```

But when I ran this code on my VPS a have following error:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 19:16:38) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import requests
>>> print(requests.get('https://www.kinopoisk.ru').text) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 393-401: ordinal not in range(256)
```

The python versions are the same. I don't know what is going on.

How do I fix it?

Comment: What's the output of `locale` at the command prompt at the two machines? Any differences?

Comment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

Comment: these locale are same @Joachim Isaksson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your environment uses the C os POSIX locale, Python 3.7 automatically coerces that to a UTF-8 aware locale, according to pep-538.

So it seems that your PC has an `UTF-8` or `C` locale set, while your VPS uses `latin-1`.

Try running the following in an interactive Python session on both machines:

```
import sys
import locale

print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
```

It you do not want to change the locale on your VPS, you could set `PYTHONUTF8=1` in its environment, or you could use the `-X utf-8` option with Python.

Comment: thanks, when i added PYTHONUTF8=1, everything started to work

Comment: My script worked on the command line, but not in cron.  The solution, found using your directions, was to change `LANG="en_US"` to `LANG="en_US.utf8"` in my crontab.  Cheers!  :-)

Comment: how to add PYTHONUTF8=1?  Which file do you add this?

Comment: @Nguaial It is an environment variable. How you set this depends on the operating system you're using.

Comment: @AstroFloyd It may happen that the UTF-8 locale is missing in which case under Linux you would have to generate it first via `locale-gen en_US.utf8`. You would need admin privileges to run this command.