# Store JSON in database with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I've been having trouble storing JSON to database with non ASCII characters.
Here's what I have so far. I'm using python requests library.

```
getJSON = requests.get('https://jsonapi.com/jsonfile')
storeDB = requests.post(
                'http://databaseAPI/Database/item', 
                data='{"payload": %s}' % (getJSON.text), 
                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            )
```

But it's failing with this error because my JSON contains non ASCII character. How can I fix that?

Error -

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "addKonvo.py", line 134, in <module>
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1297, in _send_request
    body = _encode(body, 'body')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 170, in _encode
    (name.title(), data[err.start:err.end], name)) from None
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u20ac' in position 505: Body ('€') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.```
````

Answer (score 0):

you need to encode the data in UTF-8 format using `getJSON.text.encode('utf8')`

Comment: I just did that but now I'm getting this error from the API. 'b' is an invalid start of a value. Everytime I encode it adds `b` at the beginning of json. And the API is expecting JSON

Comment: It is converting the text to bytes, can you try with ```getJSON.text.encode('utf8').decode('utf8')```

Comment: Getting same error. It's converting it back to non ASCII

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298260/how-to-fix-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-in-requests] This might be the issue I think.