# python requests .encode("utf-8") results in internal server error

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an application that sends a python requests to a web app (that I own). The application works fine until I pass a character like "Δ" into it. I then get the error `latin-1 codec can't encode characters in position in requests`. I found a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298260/how-to-fix-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-in-requests) that had the same problem. And I implemented the fix as seen below.

```
r_body = ""
for i in range(len(fronts)):
    ...
    temp_front = fronts[i]
    temp_back = backs[i]
    r_body = r_body + 'front{n}={f}&back{n}={b}&'.format(n=i, f=temp_front, b=temp_back) # temp_front and temp_back are strings that may contain chars like Δ

r_body = r_body + 'tag1=&tag2=&tag3='
r_body = r_body.encode('utf-8') # if I exclude this line of code I get the latin-1 one error - if I include it the web server responds with a 500 internal server error.
cookie = cookies[random.randint(0, (len(cookies)) - 1)] # gets random session cookie
r_response = requests.post(end_url + '/post/upload', cookies=cookie, headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, data=r_body)
```

When I exclude the line `r_body = r_body.encode('utf-8')` the request sends and no error occurs. However when the line of code is included the server responds with a "500 internal server error". If anyone has any tips on how to fix or trouble shoot my code please share.

Edit: After a long time debugging I have resolved that the internal server error occurs when ever a user agent python requests sends a request. Gunicorn for some reason prints out the request to the console which is odd. Since I am not ssh'ed into the server it throws an error.

I was able to prevent the error by starting the server such that it would not print anything to the console.

Comment: Probably not possible to debug without knowing what the server does when it receives a post request. But my guess would be it's trying to decode `r_body` as a codec other than `utf-8`.

Comment: If you are getting a 500 error in the server code, why aren't you also  posting a minimal reproducible example of the server code?

Comment: After a long time debugging I have resolved that the internal server error occurs when ever a user agent python requests sends a request. Gunicorn for some reason prints out the request to the console which is odd. Since I am not ssh'ed into the server it throws an error.