# Python Poetry Failing on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, python-poetry

I am trying to get Poetry (python dependency manager) working on Ubuntu 18.04 but it keeps throwing an odd error whenever a package is trying to be added to a project. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling poetry but it did nothing. The ubuntu machine was a clean install with barely anything on it.

The error is here: https://gist.github.com/tylermanning/6881ba664236e25434f8d0befd4a8bfc

**System information:**

- Platform: ubuntu 18.04
- Poetry version 1.1.5
- Base Python: 3.8.5
- Location of base Python: `/opt/anaconda/latest/bin/python`

**How i installed poetry:**

1. curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python
2. source the thing so poetry can be used immediately with `source $HOME/.poetry/env`
3. create a new project with poetry like `poetry new tes-proj`
4. launch `poetry shell` from inside `test-proj` directory
5. Try `poetry show` or `poetry add [some package]` and the error will be thrown

Comment: you need a lockfile for `poetry show` to work, I think. Does running `poetry lock` or just `poetry install` solve the issue?

Comment: it might also have to do with the python interpreter that conda provides. In my test I did a source-install: https://gist.github.com/a-recknagel/dddfce44ffa8e6eacd5c06f64cfe0bb0

Comment: Thanks yeah I think it's a combination of things. I found a solution that I will post soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with this was the ubuntu machine was not correctly encoding utf-8 in `locale`. Here is a more in depth issue explaining it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57298412

The fix was to simply add `export PYTHONUTF8=1` to my `~/.bash_profile`